# Angular2 AOT for dynamic HTML

Tags: angular, aot, dynamic-html, angular-compiler-cli

I have dynamic HTML in Angular2 app using [Angular2-Component-Outlet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-component-outlet) and it works. But now when I am trying to create AOT, I still need to load the RuntimeCompiler for Angular2-Component-Outlet.

Is there any way to also AOT compile the dynamic HTML and load the module using lazy loading.

An old [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/vTTRaWC4oOuU5TSZxLfk/) showing usage of Angular2-Component-Outlet to put dynamic content. This is similar to AngularJS ng-include directive.

Comment: Please share the code that demonstrates what you are dogin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could do AOT of complete project by adapting [Dynamic Form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) approach as designed in the Angular2 documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `angular2-component-outlet` is discontinued in favour of [**ng-dynamic**](https://github.com/laco0416/ng-dynamic).

Either way, both solutions require the dependency of the `RuntimeCompiler`. And this makes sense if you think about it. It's a dynamic component, based on what I guess is user input. Or at least input which is not known beforehand by the ahead-of-time compiler.

To be able to compile this input in runtime, you would need the `RuntimeCompiler`. I cannot see a way around that.

*addition*

From ng-dynamic readme:

> **dynamicComponent Constraints**
>
> dynamicComponent needs `RuntimeCompiler`. You can use AoT compilation,
>   but you **cannot** eliminate the dependency on `@angular/compiler`.

Comment: Yes, logically it's clear the requirement of RuntimeCompiler. What I am exploring is since I know my dynamic HTML will only use let's say my 10 custom components, and  I load the AOT of those component on page load as CommonJS module  then can I load the dynamic HTML converted to CommonJS module dynamically.